# Understanding how to reverse a Linked List?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have the following code for reversing a linked list:

```
node old = head;
head = null;

while (old!=null) {
   node temp = old.link;
   old.link = head;
   head = old;
   old = temp;
}
```

Can someone please explain each line of this code because I am trying to see how this reverses  the list by drawing out box diagrams but I still don't understand.

Comment: This question will likely get closed, but if you actually take the trouble of drawing the boxes (take a picture) and ask a specifc question on that you will have better chance of a response that you can learn something from.

Comment: Let us say you have a list `35 -> 42 -> 7 -> 80` now can you work out what happens to the variables in the loop?

Comment: Draw more diagrams.  Or, better, write out the state of each variable after each iteration, including what is linked to what.  Start with a list of 4-5 elements.

Comment: I figured it out after drawing the diagrams again. Thank you!!

Comment: @AayushK : I just noticed that on one of your previous questions someone suggested that you follow appropriate Java naming conventions. I feel I should suggest that to you again, all class names in Java should start with a capital letter (`Node` instead of `node`). Variable names should start with a lower-case letter with each subsequent word capitalised ([Camel Case](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)) like this: `linkedList` or `thisIsCamelCase`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `head` is a pointer to the head of a list (1, 2, 3, 4):

```
+-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
|  1  | ---> |  2  | ---> |  3  | ---> |  4  | ---> null
+-----+      +-----+      +-----+      +-----+
 ^ head
```

node old = head;
head = null;

```
+-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
|  1  | ---> |  2  | ---> |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
+-----+      +-----+      +-----+      +-----+
 ^ old

                                                     null

                                                      ^ head
```

(first iteration of `while` loop...)
node temp = old.link;

```
+-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
|  1  | ---> |  2  | ---> |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
+-----+      +-----+      +-----+      +-----+
 ^ old        ^ temp

                                                     null

                                                     ^ head
```

old.link = head;

```
+-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
|  1  | -+   |  2  | ---> |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
+-----+  |   +-----+      +-----+      +-----+
 ^ old   |    ^ temp
         |                            
         +---------------------------------------->  null

                                                     ^ head
```

head = old;

```
+-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
|  1  | -+   |  2  | ---> |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
+-----+  |   +-----+      +-----+      +-----+
 ^ old   |    ^ temp
 ^ head  |                             
         +---------------------------------------->  null
```

old = temp;

```
             +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
             |  2  | ---> |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
             +-----+      +-----+      +-----+
              ^ old
              ^ temp                   +-----+
                                       |  1  | --->  null
                                       +-----+
                                        ^ head
```

(second iteration...)
node temp = old.link;

```
             +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
             |  2  | ---> |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
             +-----+      +-----+      +-----+
              ^ old        ^ temp
                                       +-----+ link
                                       |  1  | --->  null
                                       +-----+
                                        ^ head
```

old.link = head;

```
             +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
             |  2  | -+   |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
             +-----+  |   +-----+      +-----+
              ^ old   |    ^ temp
                      |                +-----+ link
                      +--------------> |  1  | --->  null
                                       +-----+
                                        ^ head
```

head = old;

```
             +-----+ link +-----+ link +-----+ link
             |  2  | -+   |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
             +-----+  |   +-----+      +-----+
              ^ old   |    ^ temp
              ^ head  |                +-----+ link
                      +--------------> |  1  | --->  null
                                       +-----+
```

old = temp;

```
                          +-----+ link +-----+ link
                          |  3  | ---> |  4  | --->  null
                          +-----+      +-----+
                           ^ old
                           ^ temp

                          +-----+ link +-----+ link
                          |  2  | ---> |  1  | --->  null
                          +-----+      +-----+
                           ^ head
```

Repeat til `old` points to the null at the end (that is, til the original list is empty).

Comment: Did you do this by hand? I'm impressed! +1

Comment: +1 LOL - now do it with doubly-linked list :)))

Comment: @alfasin - Actually, a doubly-linked list is trivial.

Comment: @HotLicks yes, but it's still funny :)

Comment: @alfasin - Earlier I noticed, in the sidebar list of "similar" questions, one that was "how to reverse a doubly-linked list".

Answer (score 4):

```
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       |  A  |   |  B  |   |  C  |
       |     |   |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+


node old = head
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       |  A  |   |  B  |   |  C  |
       |     |   |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
         ^^^
         old

head = null
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head   |     |-->|     |-->|     |-->null
vvvv   |  A  |   |  B  |   |  C  |
null   |     |   |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
         ^^^      ^^^^
         old      temp


node temp = old.link
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head   |     |-->|     |-->|     |-->null
vvvv   |  A  |   |  B  |   |  C  |
null   |     |   |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
         ^^^      ^^^^
         old      temp

old.link = head
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head   |     |   |     |-->|     |-->null
vvvv   |  A  |   |  B  |   |  C  |
null<--|     |   |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
         ^^^      ^^^^
         old      temp

head = old
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
head-->|     |   |     |-->|     |-->null
       |  A  |   |  B  |   |  C  |
null<--|     |   |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
         ^^^      ^^^^
         old      temp

Rearranging slightly
old = temp
       +-----+
       |     |
       |  A  |
head-->|     |-->null
       +-----+
       +-----+   +-----+
 old-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       |  B  |   |  C  |
       |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+
        ^^^^
        temp
Note that A is now a valid (if short) linked list.


node temp = old.link
       +-----+
       |     |
       |  A  |
head-->|     |-->null
       +-----+
       +-----+   +-----+
 old-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       |  B  |   |  C  |
       |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+
                  ^^^^
                  temp

old.link = head
       +-----+
       |     |
       |  A  |
head-->|     |-->null
       +-----+
          ^
          |
       +-----+   +-----+
 old-->|     |   |     |-->null
       |  B  |   |  C  |
       |     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+
                  ^^^^
                  temp

head = old
       +-----+
       |     |
       |  A  |
       |     |-->null
       +-----+
          ^
          |
       +-----+   +-----+
 old-->|     |   |     |-->null
       |  B  |   |  C  |
head-->|     |   |     |
       +-----+   +-----+
                  ^^^^
                  temp

Rearrange,
old = temp
       +-----+   +-----+
       |     |   |     |
       |  B  |   |  A  |
head-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       +-----+   +-----+


       +-----+
 old-->|     |-->null
       |  C  |
       |     |
       +-----+
        ^^^^
        temp
Guess what? The sub-list A-B is now a valid list B-A.

node temp = old.link
       +-----+   +-----+
       |     |   |     |
       |  B  |   |  A  |
head-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       +-----+   +-----+


       +-----+
 old-->|     |-->null
       |  C  |    ^
       |     |    |
       +-----+    |
                  |
                 temp

old.link = head;
       +-----+   +-----+
       |     |   |     |
       |  B  |   |  A  |
head-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       +-----+   +-----+
          ^
          |
       +-----+
 old-->|     |-->null
       |  C  |    ^
       |     |    |
       +-----+    |
                  |
                 temp

head = old;
       +-----+   +-----+
       |     |   |     |
       |  B  |   |  A  |
       |     |-->|     |-->null
       +-----+   +-----+
          ^
          |
       +-----+
 old-->|     |   null
       |  C  |    ^
head-->|     |    |
       +-----+    |
                  |
                 temp

old = temp;
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+
       |     |   |     |   |     |
       |  C  |   |  B  |   |  A  |
head-->|     |-->|     |-->|     |-->null
       +-----+   +-----+   +-----+

old-->null<--temp

Old is null, break out of the loop, we're done!
```

Answer (score 3):

**It helps to draw what happens at each line of code**

Hopefully you can follow this, I numbered each line of code up to the loop 1-3, then inside the loop being A,B,C,D like this:

```
1. Node old = head;
2. head = null;

3. while (old!=null) {
A.    Node temp = old.link;
B.    old.link = head;
C.    head = old;
D.    old = temp;
   }
```

[image: First page]
[image: Second Page]

Edit: Woops it cut the bottom diagram a little bit. Head should point to the new first Node (the last Node in the diagram). Temp and Old should both be Null. And the Node that used to be first, now points to Null because it is now the last Node. Therefore it is successfully reversed.

Comment: Probably a better idea than the ascii art monstrosity I'm working on.

Comment: Haha I spent a while trying to figure out how to draw it then I remembered what Pen and Paper is!